# Cypress Get Attribute value and store in Variable

Tags: automation, cypress

I want to get the Attribute value and store in a variable how we can achieve this in cypress

In my case I want to get the complete class value and store it in variable.

This code just give me the attribute class value but how I can store the fetch value in variable

```js
cy.get('div[class*="ui-growl-item-container ui-state-highlight ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-growl-message"]').invoke('attr', 'class')
```

Answer (score 8):

I was trying to compare the style of one element with another to make sure they were equal. Here's the code that seems to work for me.

```
cy.get('.searchable-group-selector-card-image')
  .eq(4)
  .invoke('attr', 'style')
  .then(($style1) => {
    const style1 = $style1
  })
```

Answer (score 8):

A good way to solve this kind of scenario is to use the **alias** mechanism. One could leverage this functionality to enqueue multiple elements and then check all of them together by chaining the results. I've recently come to a case in an SPA where the assertion had to happen between elements that were spread across different angular routes (call them different pages).

In your use case, this would like:

```js
cy.get('.searchable-group-selector-card-image')
  .eq(4)
  .invoke('attr', 'style')
  .as('style_1')

cy.get('.another-element')
  .invoke('attr', 'style')
  .as('style_2')


// later on for example you could do
cy.get('@style_1').then(style_1 => {
  cy.get('@style_2').then(style_2 => {
    // Both values are available and any kind of assertion can be performed
    expect(style_1).to.include(style_2)
  });
});
```

This is described in [Variables and Aliases](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases#Aliases) section of the Cypress Documentation.

Comment: this is wrong, you're introducing callback hell.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I got the value of for attribute in a label tag which had text "Eat" inside.

```
cy.contains('Eat').then(($label) => {
    const id = $label.attr('for');
}
```

Comment: Nice, concise answer, which worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Most important thing is to get the selector right, so it exactly finds the value you are looking for. In this case you already found it. By using `then()` gives you the ability to store it in a variable.

```js
cy.get('div[class*="ui-growl-item-container ui-state-highlight ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-growl-message"]').invoke('attr', 'class')
  .then($growl-message => {
    const message = $growl-message.text()
    //do the checks with the variable message. For example:
    cy.contains(message)
  })
```

Note that the scope of the variable is within the curly brackets. Thus using the variable has to be within those curly brackets.

Comment: yeah Im able to find the element and with next thing I want to  get the class attribute value. I have try your code but its giving error.

Comment: Here is the error and code screenshot

https://ibb.co/ysgbX2v

https://ibb.co/N1Mv1Zp

Comment: is there any solution for that ?

Comment: It seems I missed the closing bracket at the last line. Added it to my answer. Must say I'm releasing now that I'm not completely sure this is the correct answer. Using `text()` turns the yielded object (`cy.get('div[class*="ui-growl-item-container ui-state-highlight ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-growl-message"]').invoke('attr', 'class')`) to a string. But don't know if that will hold the class name.

Comment: I was afraid for that. I have no knowledge of a solution for retrieving the class value of an element. Googling for a solution didn't help either. Maybe we are trying to solve a problem you can work around, but I don't know what the actual goal is. I believe https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html could help you to such a work around.

Comment: well this is what I want 


WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(""+messagexpath+""));
String class_name = ele.getAttribute("class");

In selenium we can get any attribute value  with just getAttribute  and attribute name

Comment: I'm looking for the same, but I'm not sure how to store the value from an attribute